# How to build CodeIgniter URL with hierarchy?

Tags: codeigniter, hierarchy, codeigniter-url

I know this doesn't exactly match the form of www.example.com/class/function/ID/, but what I want to display to the user would make more sense.

This is what I would like to do:

`www.example.com/project/id/item/item_id/`

So, an example would be:

`www.example.com/project/5/item/198237/`

And this would be the behavior:

- www.example.com/project/ --> This would show a list of projects (current implementation)
- www.example.com/project/5/ --> This would show a list of items on project 5 (current implementation)
- www.example.com/project/5/item/ --> This wouldn't really mean anything different than the line above. (Is that bad?)
- www.example.com/project/5/item/198237/ --> This would show details for item 198237.

So, each item is directly associated with one and only one project.

The only way I can think how to do this is to bloat the "project" controller and parse the various parameters and control ALL views from that "project" controller. I'd prefer not to do this, because the model and view for an "item" are truly separate from the model and view of a "project."

The only other solution (that I am currently implementing and don't prefer) is to have the following:

www.example.com/project/5/
www.example.com/item/198237/

Is there any way to build a hierarchical URL as I showed at the beginning without bloating the "project" controller?

Comment: How about Route Configuration in Routes.php

Comment: Looks like that'll work. Didn't realize how powerful that was. Thank you! Could you post as an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @thephatp Did you consider the case of `/project/5/item/12345` where item 12345 does not belong to project 5? What would the behaviour be in that case?

Comment: @jadkik94 Yes I solved that by setting $config['url_suffix']='/'. Works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 options, sorted by how practical they can be:

- Use URI Routing. Define a regular expression that will use a specific controller/method combination for each URL.

Something like that could help you, in `routes.php`:

```
$route['project/'] = 'project/viewall';
$route['project/(.+)'] = 'project/view/$1';
$route['project/(.+)/item/'] = 'project/view/$1';
$route['project/(.+)/item/(.+)'] = 'item/view/$2';
```

That is, considering your controllers are item and project respectively. Also note that `$n` in the value corresponds to the part matched in the n-th parenthesis.

- Use the same controller with (or without) redirection. I guess you already considered this.
- Use redirection at a lower level, such as `ModRewrite` on Apache servers. You could come up with a rule similar to the one in `routes.php`. If you are already using such a method, it wouldn't be a bad idea to use that, but only if you are already using such a thing, and preferably, in the case of Apache, in the server configuration rather than an `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Thanks! I went with URI routing. I've got it doing exactly what I wanted plus handling invalid urls to redirect to the index or method (if a valid input is provided). Very nice.

Comment: I'm using the routing file, but I'm getting mad with the anchors. Is the only option to manually write the segment that represents the proyect id in every anchor?

Comment: @conca Yes I guess that's the only way, unless you can use names instead of indices (I'm not sure it is supported, you might want to google that). Otherwise you can just send everything that starts with `project/` to the project controller and manually do the mapping from there if you need something really complex. (see [_remap](http://www.creativedev.in/2012/04/codeigniter-remap-function/) and `$this->uri->segments`)

Answer (score 0):

You can control all of these options using [routes.php](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html) (found in the config folder). You can alternatively catch any of your URI segments using the URI class, as in `$this->uri->segment(2)`. That is if you have the URL helper loaded. That you can load by default in the autoload.php file (also in the config folder).